# Compute sum over bounded numbers prime with given number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

When I was doing some task of analytic number theory I was stuck on computing  this sum
$$S:=\frac{1}{L} \sum_{q \in \mathcal{Q}} \phi(q) \overline{a}^{\frac{1}{2}},$$
where  $\overline{a}$ is the inverse of $a$ modulo $q>0,$  $\mathcal{Q}$ is a nonempty set of numbers defined by 
$$\mathcal{Q}=\left\{q \in [Q,2Q]; \ \gcd(a,q)=1\right\}, \quad Q\geq 1$$ and 
$$L=\sum_{q \in \mathcal{Q}} \phi(q),$$ $\phi$ is the Euler function.
 Can someone help me in doing this task? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $S$ is undefined if $\exists q \to a\equiv0\pmod q,$ isn't it?

Comment: @Yuri Actually $S$ is a sum over  numbers coprime with $a$.

Comment: Okay. Then: 1) what about maximal value of Q? 2) we say about minimal positive $\bar a$?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov I want to compute or to bound this sum in terms of $Q$ and for a fixed positive integer $a$ and notice that we summand over integers $q$ coprime with $a$ and between $Q$ and $2Q$ for a positive real $Q\geq 1.$

Comment: In my opinion, we must first get data and then dig then. I can really help in the first part with clear requirements.